# Changing 1 image to slide into many images when hovering

Tags: html, css

```
  <div class ="tc-container">
    <img src ="2.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img style ="margin-top:342px;margin-left: 52px;"class ="top-img" src="3.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>

**CSS:**
/*image hover*/
  .tc-container{
      width:500px;
      height:800px;
      padding-right: 1800px;
  }
  .tc-container img{
      width: 700px;
      height: 500px;
  }
  .top-img{
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      opacity: 0;
      transition:all 0.7s ease;
  }
  .top-img:hover{
      opacity:1;
  }
```

I want to hover 1 image and can slide it into 4-5 images. That's what I am trying to do thank you for answering my question

Comment: I believe a bit more of an embellishment with your intended behavior may help. Perhaps a link to something that is emulating this behavior?

Comment: Is this the parallax effect, as seen often with bootstrap?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you mean?

```css
.tc-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  --horizontal-spacing: 105px;
}

.tc-container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: left 0.2s ease-in;
}

.tc-container:hover #img1 {
  left: calc(3 * var(--horizontal-spacing));
}

.tc-container:hover #img2 {
  left: calc(2 * var(--horizontal-spacing));
}

.tc-container:hover #img3 {
  left: calc(1 * var(--horizontal-spacing));
}
```

```html
<div class="tc-container">
  <img id="img1" class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1022/100">
  <img id="img2" class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/100">
  <img id="img3" class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/100">
  <img id="img4" class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/102/100">
</div>
```